# How to disable MySQL server from constantly running in the background?

Tags: server, mysql, sql

[This website](https://linuxize.com/post/how-to-install-mysql-on-ubuntu-18-04/) explains MySQL server installation in Ubuntu 18.04. Basically you issue the command `sudo apt install mysql-server`. The same website then explains that:

> Once the installation is completed, the MySQL service will start
>   automatically. To check whether the MySQL server is running, type:
>   `sudo systemctl status mysql`

Does this imply that once I install `mysql-server` it will always be running in the background unless I explicitly kill the process upon each reboot?

I want to play around with `mysql-server` occasionally, but don't want it constantly running in the background.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> Does this imply that once I install mysql-server it will always be running in the background

Yes.

> unless I explicitly kill the process upon each reboot?

No, never ever ever kill mysql. Killing it can damage your database.

- `sudo service mysql stop` will stop the current session
- `sudo systemctl disable mysql` to prevent it starting on boot. That is done once and makes it disabled each boot. `sudo service mysql start` will start mysql when disabled.

Comment: Do I need to `sudo systemctl disable mysql` once at the command line to disable indefinitely? Or do I need to add this `sudo systemctl disable mysql` command to some startup script to run each time I boot Ubuntu? Thank you.

Comment: That is done once.

Comment: and final question, when I `sudo apt install mysql-workbench` do I need to worry about following any similar process? Or does MySQL Workbench have nothing to do with running a server, hence I just click the `x` to close it like any other program (Blender, LibreOffice, etc.)?

Comment: "hence I just click the x to close it like any other program"  yes.